# How can I read in user names from a CSV column and add relevant data from Active Directory to their row?

Tags: csv, powershell, active-directory

Using [this wonderful script](https://4sysops.com/archives/create-a-list-of-local-administrators-with-powershell/), I am able to scan a list of computers and output their local administrator accounts into a nice little CSV file. Below is a sample:

```
ComputerName     LocalGroupName  Status      MemberType      MemberDomain    MemberName
Computer1        Administrators  SUCCESS     LocalUser       Computer1       LocalBob
Computer1        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainUser      DomainXYZ       User99874
Computer1        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainGroup     DomainXYZ       Group123
Computer2        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainGroup     DomainXYZ       GroupABC
Computer2        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainUser      DomainXYZ       User18834
```

I'd like to include more Powershell scripting to the end of the above script to add the local admin's "Department" and "Name" field from active directory into a column which will help out generating more meaningful reports on who has local admin and why. Below is an example of what I'd like the output to look like:

```
ComputerName     LocalGroupName  Status      MemberType      MemberDomain    MemberName    Name    Department
Computer1        Administrators  SUCCESS     LocalUser       Computer1       LocalBob
Computer1        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainUser      DomainXYZ       User99874     Nick    IT
Computer1        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainGroup     DomainXYZ       Group123
Computer2        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainGroup     DomainXYZ       GroupABC
Computer2        Administrators  SUCCESS     DomainUser      DomainXYZ       User18834     Adam    Sales
```

As someone who is still fairly new to Powershell, I can understand examples of pulling information from AD and creating new CSV files, but I can't seem to wrap my mind around how to go about appending these details to the pre-existing CSV file. My thought process for how to tackle it is this:

1. Import CSV File
2. Pull usernames from each row of the *MemberName* column
3. Perform a query against AD for each of the relevant fields for each of the users
4. Populate the *Name* and *Department* rows with that user's query results.

Hopefully this all makes sense. I'm sure this is all pretty basic but I've been starring at it for a while now and I am not sure where to begin.

Thanks!

Comment: Why not modify the original script to get that information from AD at the same time as you populate the original CSV ?

Comment: It might be easier to get your head around it if you output a _new_ CSV file as the results instead of trying to modify the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have [RSAT](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2202.remote-server-administration-tools-rsat-for-windows-client-and-windows-server-dsforum2wiki.aspx) installed on your computer (which I recommend), pulling information from AD is trivial:

```
$sInFile = "C:\input.csv" # Change to actual path
$sOutFile = "C:\ouput.csv" # Change to actual path

Import-Module -Name "ActiveDirectory"
# If you don't need last names, remove "sn" from the collection.
$cProperties = @("givenName", "sn", "depatment")

$cCsv = Import-Csv -Path $sInFile

foreach ($oRow in $cCsv) {
    if ($oRow.MemberType -eq "DomainUser") {
        $oUser = Get-ADUser -Identity $oRow.MemberName -Properties $cProperties
        foreach ($sProperty in $cProperties) {
            $oRow | Add-Member -MemberType "NoteProperty" -Name $sProperty `
                -Value $oUser.$sProperty
        }
    }
}   

$cCsv | Export-Csv -Path $sOutFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding "UTF8"
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I do use RSAT frequently so I am all set on that front. This should get me started in the right direction. I put this into a new script and changed the input/output files however it didn't seem to make any changes to the output. I'll continue troubleshooting and post my solution when I get it working. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: After some troubleshooting, I figured out the column "DomainUser" was causing the issue. Renaming it to anything else (and subsequently changing the line `if ($oRow.MemberType -eq "DomainUser") {` to match) fixed it and it worked just as anticipated. Thanks for your help, this resolved my issue.